# Given name versus nickname at work

Tags: personal-name

During an instant message conversation with my supervisor, she brought to my attention that I am using the given name of an employee instead of the preferred name this person wants people to call her.  My supervisor claims that this is a professional courtesy to call this coworker by the preferred name and it would eliminate any tension in our group between me and this person.  This coworker's given name is Maria and she wants people to call her Mari.  In Spanish the two names sound very different.

My question is should my supervisor had brought this to my attention?  Also I don't see how it could be unprofessional  I am calling this person by their given name.  I am not calling her out of her name.  I don't see how it's unprofessional.

Comment: Your supervisor brought it to your attention because, frankly, it is rude to not call somebody by their preferred name, particularly if they have asked you to.

Comment: Is this a joke?

Comment: Could you tell the reasons for not using her preferred name?

Comment: Note that this is a problem a lot in high schools where students want to be named by their nickname and many teachers say "This is not your name!"

Answer (score 5):

This seems like something you should clearly do. You should even welcome the "hint" from the supervisor that Mari has preferences and that others are honoring them. In general, I believe, we should take a bit of care with our co-workers and go along with things that aren't clearly evil and might do a bit of good.

Maybe you are happy with your given name and never thought much about whether used it or not.

The opposite problem is probably worse, where someone decides to give you a "nickname", like Mich, that you don't appreciate.

After the "hint" it would be a serious error to use your preference, rather than hers.

In my case, my spouse is pretty much the only person with permission to use my given name. Everyone else uses the nickname I grew up with. My given name sounds harsh to me when used by others.